# Xamarin.Forms PCL - Android project Layout calls issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, warnings

I am making a simple button in a view

```
<Button Image="check_menu.png" IsVisible="{Binding isTrue}" BackgroundColor="Transparent"
          VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="28" HeightRequest="64"
          Command="{Binding makeAnimation}" />
```

after compiling i finish with this warning : 
**W/View : requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.*CalledLayout* during layout: running second layout pass**

I am trying to find a solution to it.

P.S. : ***CalledLayout*** can be any controller : button, label, image ...

Comment: Can you add the xaml for your whole layout? It may help someone figure out what's wrong.

Comment: From the warning, the `requestLayout()` was called for multiple times, could you please post your detailed codes?